# What fruit trees requires the most water?

Tags: fruit-trees, watering, fruits

I just moved into a home (zone 5) and there's a small part of our backyard that is often wet from how the water flows with the surrounding homes.

Are there any fruit trees that consume more water than others (and in turn would help some minor water issues in the backyard)?  I'd love a fig tree and supposedly Hardy Chicago Fig's can survive in zone 5.  However, I'm not sure what their water consumption is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really are not many fruit trees that will tolerate wet feet. They may grow OK for awhile, but their lives are likely to be shortened by root rot. You might be able to grow Juneberries there. They're a small native tree with blueberry-like berries. They tolerate wet soil better than cultivated fruits. I'd plant the fig tree elsewhere if you want to grow one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Given this I might need to ask another question about a regular non-fruit tree that does well with wet soil.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson willows and black alder immediately spring to my mind.